# Can we initialize structure memebers through smart pointer in initialization list?

Tags: c++

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

class classA
{
protected:
    struct StructB
    {
        int iAge;
        double dPrice;
    };

    boost::scoped_ptr<StructB> m_scpStructB;

public:
    classA(int age, double price)
        : m_scpStructB(new StructB)
    {
        m_scpStructB->iAge = age;
        m_scpStructB->dPrice = price;
    }

    /* DO NOT COMPILE  <= second block
    classA(int age, double price)
        : m_scpStructB(new StructB),
          m_scpStructB->iAge(age),
          m_scpStructB->dPrice(price)
    {}
    */

};
```

Question1> I have found that I cannot use the second block of code to initialize structure members pointed by a smart pointer. Is it a general c++ rule that we just cannot do it.

Please discard this question if the answer to the first question is "You cannot do it".

Question2> As far as I know, the order of assignment on initialization list is based on the order of member variables definition. Assume that you can initialize the member variables through smart pointer. How can you guarantee the order so that the smart point is initialized always first?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't *need* `StructB` to be an aggregate/POD type, then just give it a constructor too:

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

class classA
{
protected:
    struct StructB
    {
        StructB(int age, double price) : iAge(age), dPrice(price) { }

        int iAge;
        double dPrice;
    };

    boost::scoped_ptr<StructB> m_scpStructB;

public:
    classA(int age, double price) : m_scpStructB(new StructB(age, price)) { }
};
```

Otherwise you can just use a factory function, so that it remains a POD type:

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

class classA
{
protected:
    struct StructB
    {
        int iAge;
        double dPrice;

        static StructB* make(int age, double price)
        {
            StructB* ret = new StructB;
            ret->iAge = age;
            ret->dPrice = price;
            return ret;
        }
    };

    boost::scoped_ptr<StructB> m_scpStructB;

public:
    classA(int age, double price) : m_scpStructB(StructB::make(age, price)) { }
};
```

Comment: This would still work with {} instead of () without the constructor, right?

Comment: @chris : AFAIK, no, that syntax does not mix with `new`, and if it does, it would be C++11-only.

Comment: Ah, wasn't sure about it mixing with `new` or not. Guess I can try it myself to make sure.

Comment: Tried it. Works in C++11: http://ideone.com/8uZe1, fails in C++03: http://ideone.com/BpKwd.

Comment: @ildjarn, I may not give my question clearly as it should be. Thank you for your answer but it doesn't address my original question. I know those solutions you have given.

Comment: @q0987 : As chris demonstrated, it is indeed possible in C++11, just not in C++03. Beyond that, it's not really clear to me what your question is.